# Should I use TIFF or PNG Maps

Tags: geotiff-tiff, png, deep-learning

I have a school project in which I should forecast the UV index based on historical data in former UV maps.

This website http://www.soda-is.com/pub/files/iresen/ includes the UV maps both in TIFF and PNG format.

I don't know which format to use. I believe PNGs being light will help me accelerate the data processing part, however, I don't know if I will miss out on data if I exclude TIFF Maps.

Let's take for example these two maps of the same area in the same time:

PNG format: http://www.soda-is.com/pub/files/iresen/morroco_uva_2206071100_gf.png 10K sized

TIFF format: http://www.soda-is.com/pub/files/iresen/morroco_uva_2206071100.tif 269K sized

Can you see any difference ?

Comment: The TIF file has 128 colors (grayscale), where as the PNG has only 12 colors. So, yes, the TIF has more information.

Comment: I believe this question should be reopened because it asks the factual question: 'which of these two files contains more information'?

Answer (score 1):

Both PNG and TIF are lossless compression formats so you are not loosing information with either format. [See here for a comparison](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/file-types/image/comparison/tiff-vs-png.html).  I see that there is no associated world file for the PNG (the inage is not going to draw or be distributed on the surface of the earth and is less useful to you in a GIS).  Similarly the tif is not a geotiff and also does not contain any geospatial data.  Below is the output from gdalinfo.  Both file types are relatively small so the processing difference is likely to go unnoticed unless you have  antiquated computer resource.

```
gerry@gerry:~/Downloads$ gdalinfo m.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: m.tif
Size is 570, 483
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  483.0)
Upper Right (  570.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  570.0,  483.0)
Center      (  285.0,  241.5)
Band 1 Block=570x14 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Absolutely, both are not georeferenced. This is not a problem for now. What I aim for is just to get the value of each pixel in the Map. The PNG map is choropleth so I suppose that I should convert to the index according to a color pallet.   What about the TIFF file, I could not read it. Can you please tell me what information it contains.

Comment: TIFF may use also lossy compression like JPEG. There is nothing special in that TIFF file, it is a single band 8-bit grayscale image.